# Entrypoint undefined = ./index.html

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

Hi I'm a fairly new programmer in webpack, I am trying to create react app using webpack. but i am getting this error.

---

### Error

```
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
1 asset
Entrypoint undefined = ./index.html
```

### webpack.config.js

```
[![const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path')

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html"
});
module.exports = {
  entry: "index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
    module: {
      rules: \[
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
                "presets": \["env", "react"\]   
            }
          }
        }
      \]
    },
    plugins: \[htmlPlugin\],
    devServer: {
      contentBase: './dist',
      hot: true
    }
  };
```

### This is My Project structure

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve1oa.png]

Comment: Does it work if you just remove the `filename` property from the `HtmlWebPackPlugin` options entirely?

Comment: then what should I write on the place of filename??

Comment: it is ok, that is an autogenerated html, and it is normal to show entrypoint=undefined on webpack output.

Comment: I removed filename: "./index.html" from web pack.config file but still giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `filename: "./index.html"` should be `filename: "index.html"` ? 
Or just remove it

Comment: try just removing this line

Comment: you removed just the `filename` ?

Comment: i removed filename: "./index.html" from webpack.config file but still giving same error

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this error message is harmless and can be ignored: [html-webpack-plugin issue #895](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/895)